# AWS lambda event reprocess request

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Sometimes my backend database goes offline and the AWS lambda execution which requires this backend fails. Can I ask AWS to reprocess the same event in a later time hoping that the backend goes online by that time? I'm using node.js for my lambda code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AWS lambda's DLQ service. It sends all failed executions to SNS/SQS, you can review them and reprocess them from their.

Link to doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html (scroll to AWS Lambda function dead-letter queues)